# Is there any reason not to allow all characters for usernames in my php program?

Tags: php

For my first php website, I'm currently allowing all characters to be used in usernames. When they are inserted into the database, I use addslashes(), and when they are retrieved from the database, I use stripslashes(), and then I use htmlentities() to cause them to display properly on the page. I haven't had any problems so far, but are there any characters that I should disallow in usernames for any reason? HTML, CSS, and PHP are the only languages I'm fluent in, and I'm concerned that in the future I will come across functions in PHP or Java or some other language that will have difficulty parsing certain characters.

Comment: `addslashes()` is old school and probably a problem in and of itself. Try `mysqli_` functions/methods or PDO. To answer your question, technically no, you should not care what your users are using character wise for usernames, *except* if you're **not** properly handling it. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should've put this as an answer, I would've selected it.

Comment: The reality is, though, I'd suggest using email addresses as login usernames (as opposed to "plain name" usernames for display). It's easy (easier) to administer, but you still need to understand what's valid in an email address as well.

Comment: That's a good idea. It's easier for users to remember their login information that way, too. Any other tips while you're at it?

Comment: If you can, implement OpenID. Take it all off your hands. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of characters could cause problems:

Obviously there are the characters with special meaning in html and SQL, which you have dealt with.

Other possibilities are:

- For searching users, regular expression characters/wildcards, eg. *, ?
- If you want to give users an email address, emails only support alphanumeric characters, underscores and non-adjacent dots, and many systems assume emails are case-insensitive (although not part of the specification)
- If you want to give users a profile page where the url contains their username, many characters will needed to be encoded properly.
- Non-ascii characters could cause problems, depending on how usernames are stored (if they are stored in fields supporting UTF-8, then any character is supported)

Comment: Hmm, good things to think about. So what about string functions? Are there any pitfalls I might run into with those?

Comment: Don't think string functions themselves will cause any problems. The main problems occur when the username is embedded in code which will be parsed (eg. by SQL, HTML, URL), because it is embedded in a programming language.

Comment: But there are functions to escape special characters for SQL, HTML, and the URL, right?